# problem antlrworks code too large

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr3, antlrworks

In Antlrworks I get this error:

```
 [18:21:03] Checking Grammar Grammar.g...
 [18:21:26] Grammar.java:12: code too large
 [18:21:26]     public static final String[] tokenNames = new String[] {
 [18:21:26]                                  ^
 [18:21:26] 1 error
```

Using instead the generated code in a Java project works normally. What can be had this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For larger grammars, it's easier to split your grammar into bite-sized chunks (at least a separate lexer and parser). If you do so, ANTLRWorks will probably stop complaining as well.

Checkout the Wiki entry about [*"Composite grammars"*](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Composite+Grammars).